# Option with 1 to 1000

Tags: html

Can some one give me a html option tag thats goes from 1 to 100 ?

Comment: You can do this. Just start typing.

Comment: Or, as Gauss once said, `<option>5050</option>`

Comment: 1 to 100 or 1 to 1000? You'd better clear this up.

Comment: You might instead ask how to do this with javascript. That would be a programming question.

Comment: Better use a text field with input control, it will be less boring for the user than to choose from such combo box. Always found the birthday year choosers annoying to use (all that scroll...).

Answer (score 5):

In PHP:

```
foreach (range(0,100) as $number)
 echo "<option value='$number'>$number</option>";
```

Answer (score 3):

jquery:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
  $(select).append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++){
    System.out.println("<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>");
}
```

Now you have 100 option tags from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in PHP do you mean something like this:

```
echo '<select>
for($i = 1; $i < 101; $i++) {
  echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the HTML-element [option] combined with "label", like so:

```
<option label="1">Option one</option>
<option label="2">Option one</option>
[...]
```

The label allows for a value that's easy to proces automatically, and the text between the option-tags should be used to display something that's meaningful to the user.

Answer (score 0):

in HTML5: `<input type="range" min="1" max="100" />` or `<input type="number" min="1" max="100" />`

Answer (score 0):

In javascript (I'm a bit rusty, untested):

```
select = document.getElementById('your-list'); 
for(i=0; i<=100; i++) {
    option = document.createElement('option');
    option.setAttribute('value', i);
    option.innerHTML = i;
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```